# Why doesn't TimeSerial compute a correct value for negative second value?

Tags: time, vbscript

Just facing a new weird behavior (or bug) in VBScript:

```
WScript.Echo TimeSerial(0, 0, 15)
WScript.Echo TimeSerial(0, 0, -15)
WScript.Echo TimeSerial(1, 0, 15)
WScript.Echo TimeSerial(1, 0, -15)
WScript.Echo TimeSerial(1, 1, 15)
WScript.Echo TimeSerial(1, 1, -15)
```

outputs:

```
00:00:15
00:00:15 <- shouldn't be 23:59:45?
01:00:15
00:59:45 <- OK.
01:01:15
01:00:45 <- OK.
```

Why such unexpected output?

Help only says:

> However, you can also specify relative times for each argument using any numeric expression that represents some number of hours, minutes, or seconds before or after a certain time.

Comment: Interesting, the first also returns `00:00:15` whereas the second returns `00:59:45` as expected when I execute this. Must admit I've never used `TimeSerial()` with relative values before so never encountered this issue and it does seem like a bug on the first inspection.

Comment: The second one is a relative date/time, it actually has a negative value of 15 seconds but the string representation is not including that.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I know, when I said the *"second"* one I was referring to the second result the OP mentions `00:59:15 <- ?? should be 00:59:45` as you can see in the answer below it is.

Comment: On my computer, `TimeSerial(1, 0, -15)` ends up showing as `0:59:45`. And when  I said "second" I meant the second expression, `0, 0, -15`, it should not end up as `23:59:45`, as it doesn't represent a time, but a relative time of minus 15 seconds.

Comment: Sorry folks, but I re-run the test and I think I probably miscopied the results, because there is no such error as "00:59:15". Can't recall exactly where does it come from.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen so you mean it's rather a poor representation of "00:00:-15"?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what is happening. I think the string conversion here is only written to support *time* values, and not *relative* time values, in other words I believe the result is currently undefined for any negative value.

Comment: @maxxyme have [provided a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56933966/692942) if that helps using `DateAdd()` instead that doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: Even `TimeSerial(-1, 0, 0)` ends up as `01:00:00`, which is also clearly wrong. However, if you add it to a date, you get one hour back from midnight, `WScript.Echo (DateSerial(2019, 7, 8) + TimeSerial(-1, 0, 0))` gives `07.07.2019 23:00:00`

Comment: @Lankymart The workaround is not necessary and was due to the comment above about incorrectly copying the results, the issue that workaround solved is not an actual issue and was the result of bad copy/paste. It will not solve the problem of converting a negative result from TimeSerial correctly to a string.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes but, `TimeValue(DateAdd("h", -1 , TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)))` does come out as `23:00:00`. My point is `DateAdd()` can work around the relative time issue for you as conversion of relative time from `TimeSerial()` can't be trusted.

Comment: Yes, but that is a different result, TimeSerial with negative values gives relative time, if you don't want that, don't use TimeSerial.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Look, there might be instances where someone wants to use `TimeSerial()` as I've already said because of the issue with relative values in `TimeSerial()` you can use `DateAdd()` as a workaround to get the correct value. I don't appreciate being shot down when I've tested it and it works. A bit of mutual respect would go a miss thank you.

Comment: My apologies, I did not mean to shoot you down. My point was that I assumed there was a reason why TimeSerial was chosen to begin with, and why negative values was used here. The workaround works perfectly but does something different *than my assumption*. In essence, if you want minus one hour to become 23:00:00, TimeSerial is the wrong function to use, but that work around of course does that perfectly. Sorry for not making myself clear.

Comment: I was also commenting about the workaround for adding minus 15 seconds, I see now that that was not what you were commenting about. The workaround for correctly handling minus 15 seconds was the one I meant was not needed, as that was a result of incorrect copy and paste. TimeSerial already handled that case correctly (as per the examples in the question). Again, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug/issue here, but not with the part you suspect.

The issue here is that the function that converts the underlying variant value to a string does not correctly handle the negative numbers.

The *value* of the TimeSerial result, however, is correct, but converting it to a string, isn't.

The TimeSerial function only promises to return something that *is a time* if you provide *valid* time values, so 0-23 for hour and 0-59 for minutes and seconds. If you start using negative numbers you end up with a *relative* value, and this part is apparently not handled correctly when converting the result to a string.

As an example:

```
WScript.Echo CDbl(TimeSerial(1, 0, -15))*24
WScript.Echo 1-15/(60*60)
```

gives the same output:

```
0,995833333333333
0,995833333333333
```

let's include the time you wanted to have:

```
WScript.Echo CDbl(TimeSerial(0, 59, 45))*24
```

which also gives:

```
0,995833333333333
```

And your second example:

```
WScript.Echo CDbl(TimeSerial(0, 0, -15))*24
WScript.Echo -15/(60*60)
```

gives:

```
-4,16666666666667E-03
-4,16666666666667E-03
```

As you can see, you get back a negative value, **not a time**.

Comment: Nice piece of detective work, so it looks as though there is an inherent bug in `Time` to string conversion.

Comment: My guess is that the underlying value, which is a variant of subtype Date, does in fact store the individual values, and the conversion to a string doesn't handle negative values very well.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth using a different method to provide a relative offset for seconds, you should be able to accomplish this using `DateAdd()` and passing a `-15` then use `TimeValue()` to return just the time part.

```vb
Dim dt: dt = DateAdd("s", -15, TimeSerial(0, 0, 0))
WScript.Echo TimeValue(dt)
```

Output:

```
23:59:45
```

---

This is an interesting one it does seem to be a bug with relative seconds. Did a quick test that loops through 24 hours in 15 minute periods and subtracts 15 seconds each time and the results apart from the `00:00:00` are correct so a weird bug with midnight?

```vb
Option Explicit
Const hours = 24
Const minutes = 60
Const min_offset = 15
Const sec_offset = -15
Dim h, m, s

For h = 0 To hours - 1
  For m = 0 To minutes - 1 Step min_offset
    WScript.Echo TimeSerial(h, m, s)
    WScript.Echo TimeSerial(h, m, sec_offset)
  Next
Next
```

Output:

```
00:00:00
00:00:15
00:15:00
00:14:45
00:30:00
00:29:45
00:45:00
00:44:45
01:00:00
00:59:45
01:15:00
01:14:45
01:30:00
01:29:45
01:45:00
01:44:45
02:00:00
01:59:45
02:15:00
02:14:45
02:30:00
02:29:45
02:45:00
02:44:45
03:00:00
02:59:45
03:15:00
03:14:45
03:30:00
03:29:45
03:45:00
03:44:45
04:00:00
03:59:45
04:15:00
04:14:45
04:30:00
04:29:45
04:45:00
04:44:45
05:00:00
04:59:45
05:15:00
05:14:45
05:30:00
05:29:45
05:45:00
05:44:45
06:00:00
05:59:45
06:15:00
06:14:45
06:30:00
06:29:45
06:45:00
06:44:45
07:00:00
06:59:45
07:15:00
07:14:45
07:30:00
07:29:45
07:45:00
07:44:45
08:00:00
07:59:45
08:15:00
08:14:45
08:30:00
08:29:45
08:45:00
08:44:45
09:00:00
08:59:45
09:15:00
09:14:45
09:30:00
09:29:45
09:45:00
09:44:45
10:00:00
09:59:45
10:15:00
10:14:45
10:30:00
10:29:45
10:45:00
10:44:45
11:00:00
10:59:45
11:15:00
11:14:45
11:30:00
11:29:45
11:45:00
11:44:45
12:00:00
11:59:45
12:15:00
12:14:45
12:30:00
12:29:45
12:45:00
12:44:45
13:00:00
12:59:45
13:15:00
13:14:45
13:30:00
13:29:45
13:45:00
13:44:45
14:00:00
13:59:45
14:15:00
14:14:45
14:30:00
14:29:45
14:45:00
14:44:45
15:00:00
14:59:45
15:15:00
15:14:45
15:30:00
15:29:45
15:45:00
15:44:45
16:00:00
15:59:45
16:15:00
16:14:45
16:30:00
16:29:45
16:45:00
16:44:45
17:00:00
16:59:45
17:15:00
17:14:45
17:30:00
17:29:45
17:45:00
17:44:45
18:00:00
17:59:45
18:15:00
18:14:45
18:30:00
18:29:45
18:45:00
18:44:45
19:00:00
18:59:45
19:15:00
19:14:45
19:30:00
19:29:45
19:45:00
19:44:45
20:00:00
19:59:45
20:15:00
20:14:45
20:30:00
20:29:45
20:45:00
20:44:45
21:00:00
20:59:45
21:15:00
21:14:45
21:30:00
21:29:45
21:45:00
21:44:45
22:00:00
21:59:45
22:15:00
22:14:45
22:30:00
22:29:45
22:45:00
22:44:45
23:00:00
22:59:45
23:15:00
23:14:45
23:30:00
23:29:45
23:45:00
23:44:45
```

Comment: I think this is just a problem with the string representation. If you convert each value to a double, you'll find that the one using `(1, 0, -15)` does in fact end up with the correct value, it is just incorrectly converted to a string.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen so the bug is in the string conversion, sounds plausible.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen as mentioned above, the result of `(1, 0, -15)` is rather a non-problem as it appeared I might have badly copied the console output. Sorry for that.

Comment: @maxxyme I wasn't referring to `1, 0, -15` I was talking about `0, 0, -15`. Regardless `DateAdd()` acts as a workaround.